Avoiding data "loss" with FIR filters
I've been studying digital signal processing as it relates to software defined radios.  I've been working with the firfilt.py example from https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Cookbook/FIRFilter, which basically fakes up a waveform, creates a FIR Filter (Kaiser), and displays some of the variables.  The input and output arrays for the scipy.signal.lfilter() call are identical in length (400 samples).  The first part of the filtered samples, though, aren't useful because they "assume" that the preceding sample data was zero.  I've seen code that "compensates" by simply throwing away part of the original samples and the filtered samples in order to make the graphs of the two line up.
When it comes to an SDR, removing data like this seems pretty undesirable!  Would it be an abuse of FIR filters to work around this?  I was thinking that, since we're processing an ongoing data stream in discrete chunks (e.g. 1024 samples), would it be okay to hang onto the last N samples (don't recall the proper term for N - order or taps or some such) of the current chunk and prepend them to the next chunk?  Or is there a clever mathematical trick that I don't know?

If you're currently studying FIR filters, you will want to realize why the constant group delay of linear phase filters makes answering your question a bit easier than the general case for any filter.

Check out "overlap-add" and "overlap-save" methods of implementing filtering.

Yes what the OP suggests would make sense to do if that data was continuous in time from block to block (or equivalent as such).
The filtering can be done by an FIR filter as the OP suggests, or equivalently in the frequency domain efficiently using FFTs, which is also convenient for block processing where overlapping of streaming data in chunks is the common approach. What I detail below is specific to using an FIR filter.
An FIR filter is simply a weighted moving average in time. As our data moves through the FIR filter (or similarly as our FIR filter moves through the data), the output of the FIR filter represents the weighted average of all the samples in the FIR's memory at that moment in time.  Thus we also see how for the case of a linear phase filter (a subset of all possible filter types) which has symmetric or asymmetric coefficients, that that weighted average would represent the smoothed signal as it exists at the midpoint of the filter  (resulting in the delay of the filter not being it's length but approximately half the length or specifically $(N-1)/2$ for an N-tap linear phase FIR filter).
Both of these points are illustrated below and suggest why we would want to maintain the filter's data from one block as we transition to a subsequent data block assuming the waveform is continuous across blocks.
The data in time in a given data buffer is represented in the top row as $M$ samples, and we see the process of using an $N=5$ FIR filter to create $M$ output samples. As we start a new data block (labeled "Current Data Buffer"), the first sample out of the FIR filter would be the weighted average of the first sample in the Current Data Buffer, and the prior four samples from the Previous Data Buffer (or if we didn't maintain that filter state, all zeros as in the initial condition).

When the Previous Data Buffer represents independent data (such as a multiplexed sensor or time gaps in the waveform), there would be no advantage to maintaining the filter's prior state, and the result may actually be worst than having the all zero initial condition. In this case the output of the filter represents the inevitable transient condition we would see upon any abrupt change in data at the filter's input (as given by the filter's step response for example).
